# How do I delete this account without affecting other SE accounts?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I logged in here once (was browsing) but don't participate here and don't want this account as part of my broader SE profile.  How can I either delete it or dis-associate it?  I couldn't find anything in the "edit" options for accounts, nor any sort of "delete" link.

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account/7979#7979

Answer (score 1):

As David notes, [instructions for deleting your account can be found here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account/7979#7979) Note that you *should* have been able to self-delete your account, since you've never used it. However, since you've already gone ahead and emailed us about it, I've removed your account.

Reminder to anyone reading this that account deletion is irreversible under normal circumstances. But feel free to create a new account at any time should you later decide you want one...

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking how to delete his Christianity.SE account, [here is the form](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/user-deletion).